# Can i make money with my Android Engine or should I focus on game-making?

Tags: android

I have dedicated past few month to developing my own android 2d engine.
You can see its description, demo and tutorials.

While working on the engine I believed it to be better then most available alternatives ( such as andengine, etc. ) and that people would love to use it in their games and, hopefully, would give me some royalties.

Yet as I started posting about my engine on other forums, it start looking like people are only interested in free/opensource engines.

Based on your experience, what do you think, is there some way for me to make money with that engine or should I forget about selling it and more focus on making games with it myself?

Comment: Have you considered if there are any similar engines that make money, and how?

Comment: Not really, for example AndEngine is free. Corona is for sale, but it also can be found on torrents.

Comment: Roger, you can't expect studios to use pirated software? One of the most popular Javascrupt engines costs 99$, I think you will be fine.

Comment: With that documentation? Seriously? A library I even consider using has to have a lot going for it, if it has no reference documentation (with desciptions descriptions of all objects and methods, corner cases, exact specification of possible error paths etc.). At least generate some documentation with Doxygen or Javadoc or whatever, the doc you provide stinks with non-professionalism (I'm not speaking of the engine itself I didn't really look at that in detail).

Comment: there will be lots of tutorials. docs are just as a list of possible methods, etc.

Comment: This "question" seems pretty spam-like. Additionally, it appears to be asking for a discussion.

Comment: My two cents on the docs issue: Official docs should never be just a possibility. What if there were no official docs for Java? You probably never would have been able to make this engine without them and people who make tutorials rely on official docs. That said, I agree that this question seems more like spam than anything else.

Answer (score 2):

In my personal opinion, only cross-platform engines or specialized engines (e.g. a Soft body physics engine) will sell.

Also, I couldn't understand the features of your engine from your website. It looks like a level editor with physics functionality. If it does have more features, you need to have a "Features" section in your website. How does it handle multiple screen resolutions and aspect ratios? What is the minimum Android version supported? Have you developed a full game using the engine?

Comment: You can take a look at the demo here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=engineDemo.com

Answer (score 1):

Look at this Javascript game engine called Impact: http://impactjs.com/. I think that engines in general, if done correctly, will sell.